# How to trigger actions during animate method with Appcelerator?

Tags: animation, appcelerator

I have a simple progress bar that turns from green to red. The animate method is really very handy there. But is there a way to add actions while the animation is running (e.g. show a label after 1 second)?

views.js:

```
<View id="progressBar" height="40%" width="100%" left="0%" backgroundColor="green" onClick="checkAnimation"/>
```

controller.js:

```
$.progressBar.animate({
    left: 0,
    width: "1%",
    backgroundColor: "red",
    duration: 2000  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use setTimeout method irrespective of whatever animation is running, like this:

```
$.progressBar.animate({
    left: 0,
    width: "1%",
    backgroundColor: "red",
    duration: 2000  
});

setTimeout(function(){
   $.someLabel.visible = true; 
   // or
   $.someOtherLabel.text = "Label changed while animation is running...";
}, 1000);
```